# How to access show method in parent class from child class?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__num = 100

    def show(self):
        print("Parent:",self.__num)

class Child(Parent):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.__var = 10
    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print("Child:",self.__var)   

obj1 = Child()
obj1.show()
```

> File "main.py", line 12, in show
>       super().show()
>     File "main.py", line 6, in show
>       print("Parent:",self.__num)
>   AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '_Parent__num'

Comment: Add `super().__init__()` to your constructor

Comment: Don't use double underscore variables, they are subject to name mangling and you should get familar with that first.

Comment: @KlausD. just added this as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You  need to initialize the parent instance in your child class, because the `__num` attribute is only set during `Parent`'s initialization, and not during the `Child`'s.

```
class Child(Parent):  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__var = 10
    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print("Child:",self.__var)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__num = 100

    def show(self):
        print("Parent:",self.__num)

class Child(Parent):  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Solution
        self.__var = 10

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print("Child:",self.__var)   

obj1 = Child()
obj1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overridding try this.

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__num = 100

  def show(self):
     print("Parent:",self.__num)

class Child(Parent):  
  def __init__(self):
     Parent.__init__(self)
     self.__var=10
  def show1(self):
    print("Child:",self.__var)   

obj1 = Child()
obj1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Child.**init** to something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__var = 10
    super().__init__()
```

Answer (score 0):

as the other answers already said, you need to add `super().__init__()` to the `__init__` of your child class.

but also note that there is something called *name mangling* at work here. read e.g. the **3. Double Leading Underscore: __var** on [this page](https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python).

the short version is: if you wanted to use the attribute `self.__num` also in the child class you should rename it to `self._num` (one underscore only).